# Javascript: click event handler not working

Tags: javascript, html, web

```js
function check() {
  var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  para[0].style.fontSize = 20;
}
```

```html
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<button onClick="check()">Check</button>
```

please check the script section  I am not able to find any error please help me this

Comment: what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

Specify font size in pixels inside string instead of using number 20. Also move the script tag to bottom of body tag.

Please find the working snippit below:

```js
    function check()
    {
        var para=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
        para[0].style.fontSize= '20px' ;
    }
```

```html
    <p>This a paragraph</p>
    <p>This a paragraph</p>
    <p>This a paragraph</p>
    <p>This a paragraph</p>
    <button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For each **Tag P** must use like this...

**js**

```
function check() {
  var s=document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)
  {
    s[i].setAttribute("style","font-size:20px");
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<p>This a paragraph</p>
<button onClick="check()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the size in string with px,em,% behind and wrap it with quote

```
para[0].style.fontSize = 20;
```

to

```
para[0].style.fontSize = "20px";
```